# Is there a way to vstack() a very large array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a huge data set ([deepsig data set 2018](http://opendata.deepsig.io/datasets/2018.01/2018.01.OSC.0001_1024x2M.h5.tar.gz)) for radio signals that is organized as following:

the dataset is a .hdf5 file that has 3 keys (X, Y, Z)

- X : shape(2 555 904 x 1024 x 2) floats `over 2 Millions sample each has 1024 complex points (2 floats for real and imaginary parts)`
- Y : shape(2 555 904 x 24) integer to point on the modulation type
- Z : shape(2 555 904 x 1) integer the Signal Noise Level (SNR)

I organized both the modulation types and the SNR as a list of tuples `((mod,snr),(mod,snr),(mod,snr), ...)`

My problem is that when I extract the X data and try to organize them vertically i get a memory problem (cannot allocate enough memory, although I have 32GB RAM). here is my code:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

filename = 'RML_2018.hdf5'
f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')

X = f['X'][:]
X = np.vstack(X)
print (X.shape)
```

an here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nechi/PycharmProjects/CNN_MR_v2/cnn.py", line 11, in <module>
    X = np.vstack(X)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in vstack
  File "/home/nechi/PycharmProjects/CNN_MR_v2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 282, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (2617245696, 2) and data type float32
```

So, my questions are :

1. Is there a possible way to work around this memory issue?
2. If I want to reduce the data (for example take 512 sample instead of 1024 samples), Do you have an idea how to do it?

Comment: `X=X.reshape(-1, 2)` should do the same thing, but without the data copy. You can slice `f['X']` on any dimension: `f['X'][:,:512,:]`

Comment: @hpaulj yes but i need the data to be shaped as following : `(2 555 904 x 2 x 1024 )` isn't what **vstack()** supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the datatype is 32bit float, the full array is about 20 GB in memory, so your RAM can hold one copy of the whole array but not two. My guess is that that your MemoryError occurs when `vstack` creates another in-memory copy of the array after you created the first one with `X = f['X'][:]`. The problem is not that `vstack` would not work for large arrays, but rather that you try to handle the whole of the huge array in memory at once.

Answering your questions:

1. You could use `X_shaped = np.swapaxes(X, 1, 2)`, which would solve the issue at that point because it would create a reshaped view instead of a copy, but you would propably eventually run into memory issues later in your code.
2. Just use `f['X'][:,:512,:]` as @hpaulj suggested.

BUT: That huge dataset is in a HDF5 file for a reason. HDF5 lets you slice conveniently through your data without the need to load the whole thing into memory first, then manipulate it with numpy. In your data evaluation, you would typically iterate over your data.